# Mongosh can't execute use database in file

Tags: mongodb, mongo-shell

I'm using mongosh to execute commands for my MongoDB, and some of those commands would include changes of databases. So I need to execute commands like `use db`

I'm trying to use directly a script and use it as file with `mongosh -u user -p password --file file

However, the file (.js) doesn't recognize the `use db` command and fails in it

I've tried another approach, using `--eval` but that one is only working for me if I the command is only in one line.

`mongosh -u user -p password --eval 'rs.initiate({ _id: "database", members: [ {_id: 0, host: "mongo:27017"} ] });`

works but

```
mongosh -u <user> -p <password> --eval rs.initiate({ 
    _id: "database", 
    members: [ 
        {_id: 0, host: "mongo:27017"} 
    ] 
})'
```

Any ideas?

doesn't

Comment: Would [db.getSiblingDB()](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/db.getSiblingDB) work here?

Comment: That fixed my issues, thanks